# Norway to Paris — immigration check?

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens

My wife, my daughter and I are travelling to Paris from Kristiansand via Amsterdam on the 27th Aug. We all have Indian passports and I have a work permit for Norway.

My question is, will there be any immigration checks on our route to and from Paris? If so, is the resident card necessary for my wife to travel on this route?

My wife and daughter came to Norway recently by getting a type D visa, and they were granted  temporary residence permits from 6 July 2014. My daughter received her residence permit card, but my wife's resident card has been delayed due to some postal issues. I hope we will get the card before our travel.

We have the residence permit approval letter copy given by the police. My wife's passport has only the D visa stamp, but in that permit approval letter it is mentioned that she can travel in and out Norway.

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE. I changed the phrasing of your question slightly to reflect that it is indeed a question about travel, not migration, which is off-topic; please do not hesitate to edit it if I have misrepresented anything.

Comment: if the type D visa is still valid she can travel

Answer (score 5):

Under the Schengen agreement, “systematic” border checks have been abolished. In practice, it's very unlikely that your passport will be checked by the police but it does not mean that there cannot be any check or that the airline will not ensure you have appropriate documentation (in particular, Ryanair is notorious for that).

Legally speaking, whether a border check is likely and whether you are in fact allowed to travel are distinct questions. Holding a valid type D visa or a residence permit is definitely enough to travel to other Schengen countries or leave and reenter the area. I don't know if the “approval letter” is formally enough but it's possible (I know that similar documents from other country do authorize travels in other Schengen countries).

Comment: by an amazing coincidence I AGAIN had my passport checked, going in to geneve on thursday!  good grief!

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, will there be any immigration checks on our route to and from Paris?

No. Both Norway and Paris (well, France) are part of the [Schengen Area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area#Membership). Quoting wikipedia.org (emphasis mine),

> The Schengen Area is the area comprising 26 European countries that have **abolished passport and any other type of border control at their common borders**, also referred to as internal borders. It **functions as a single country** for international travel purposes, with a common visa policy.

Comment: the fact that there are not immigration checks doesn't mean that border police (or the equivalent title) at airports will not check the travel documents. If a citizen of a extra-eu country go to take a flight and he don't have the documentation to proof his right of stay (a visa, a residence permit, a document accepted as valid proof like a translated and legalized marriage certification) the boarding will be denied.

Comment: Good catch on the flights. Didn't think of that.

Comment: Border checks within Schengen are more common than the legislation would lead you to expect, see sites like [freemovement.net](https://freemovement.net/) for tracking them